# Refresh Button UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, refresh

I want to add a refresh button to my app so that I don't always have to quit the app to clear the data.

I have tried a `RefreshRequested`, but I can't make it work.

`C#` code:

```
private void RefreshButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshContainer.requestRefresh();
    } 

 <RefreshContainer>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="910" Height="383" Margin="0,0,0,0">

<RelativePanel 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkOliveGreen" BorderThickness="8" Background="FloralWhite" Height="356" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="871" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible" RequestedTheme="Default">

<AppBarButton x:Name="RefreshButton" Click="RefreshButtonClick"
                      Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

<TextBlock x:Name="timerLabel"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="00:00:00" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontSize="72" FontWeight="Normal"   TextAlignment="Center" Width="328" Margin="272,90,0,0"/>

 <Button Name="startButton" Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click_Start"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="311,219,0,0"/>

<Button Name="stopButton" Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click_Pause" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="398,219,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

 <Button Name="resetButton"  Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click_Reset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="498,219,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

<Button Name="restButton" Content="Parametres" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click_Rest" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="698,192,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

<TextBlock Name="Round" Text="Nombre Round" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="382,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" TextDecorations="Underline"/>

        </RelativePanel>

 </Grid>

    </RefreshContainer>
```

I expect the app data to refresh

Comment: Please look at the following example from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pull-to-refresh you will need to setup data binding to get this work, plus a data template. This is really complicated as well. An alternative solution would be to setup data binding and refresh the backing object

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had seen this solution of pull to refresh but I am looking for a refresh button where you clik on it and it refreshes your page. I tried to adapt the pull to refresh to a button but was not able to

Answer (score 0):

> Refresh Button UWP

I tested your code, the problem is you have not set a scroll-able control as RefreshContainer's content. Base on @Stuart Smith provided document, you could realize refresh feature, before that you need place the above Grid content under the `ScrollViewer`.

**Xaml**

```
<RefreshContainer Name="MyRefreshContainer" RefreshRequested="MyRefreshContainer_RefreshRequested">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="910" Height="383" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <RelativePanel
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="DarkOliveGreen" BorderThickness="8" Background="FloralWhite" Height="356" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="871" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Visible" RequestedTheme="Default">

                <AppBarButton x:Name="RefreshButton" Click="RefreshButtonClick"
              Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                <TextBlock x:Name="timerLabel"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="00:00:00" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontSize="72" FontWeight="Normal"   TextAlignment="Center" Width="328" Margin="272,90,0,0"/>

                <Button Name="startButton" Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="311,219,0,0"/>

                <Button Name="stopButton" Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="398,219,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

                <Button Name="resetButton"  Background="MediumSeaGreen" Foreground="White" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="498,219,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

                <Button Name="restButton" Content="Parametres" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="698,192,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="1.373,0.57"/>

                <TextBlock Name="Round" Text="Nombre Round" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="382,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" TextDecorations="Underline"/>

            </RelativePanel>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</RefreshContainer>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void RefreshButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRefreshContainer.RequestRefresh();
}

private async void MyRefreshContainer_RefreshRequested(RefreshContainer sender, RefreshRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    using (var RefreshCompletionDeferral = args.GetDeferral())
    {
        // Do some async operation to refresh the content




        RefreshCompletionDeferral.Complete();
        RefreshCompletionDeferral.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot ! Being an absolute beginner to programming, I don't know what await method to use in order for the refresh to work .. Could you please help me a little bit more ?

Comment: I used this : await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(); but I get this error : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Comment: @Tomas I tested calling `await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync();` in the `MyRefreshContainer_RefreshRequested` event handler it woks well. Could share a blank repro sample ?

Comment: For Asynchronous programming  please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps).

Comment: I tried your solution but when I press Refresh nothing happens. I am looking for something that would really refresh the data, or even restart the app if I can't refresh

Comment: If you just want to clear app's data , you have no need use `RefreshContainer`, it is often used to create  UI interaction.

Comment: You could set a Task delay in the `MyRefreshContainer_RefreshRequested`.    `using (var RefreshCompletionDeferral = args.GetDeferral())
{
    // Do some async operation to refresh the content

    await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync();

    await Task.Delay(2000);
    RefreshCompletionDeferral.Complete();
    RefreshCompletionDeferral.Dispose();
}`

Comment: Hello Nico Zhu, I have abandoned the refresh button as I am not able to make it work. Thank you for your help

Comment: All right, if you have any updates please feel free post here, and if the above reply is helpful please mark it, Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Tomas, I see you've abandoned the refresh button for now, but I wanted to follow up in case you revisit this later or if others run into this issue in the future.

In order for the data to refresh, you'd need to code this in.
“To get fresh content when needed, handle the RefreshRequested event. In the event handler, you'll need code specific to your app to get the fresh content.” https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pull-to-refresh#handle-a-refresh-request. There's a sample in the doc there too.

You'd typically use data binding for this and the RefreshRequested event would need to edit the bound object.

```
using (var RefreshCompletionDeferral = args.GetDeferral())
{
     await FetchAndInsertItemsAsync(3);
}
```

In the sample, you'll notice that FetchAndInsertItemsAsync is inserting new items to the backing collection.

There's more info on data binding here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart